# Overriding the search block module output to add a custom wrapper

Tags: theming, hooks

My problem is fairly simple. I have written a theme_form() to override the default but I want it to kick in only in the search block. How can I do this with Drupal 7? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put [search-block-form.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search-block-form.tpl.php/7) into your theme directory, and modify it as you wish.

Another way is using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function HOOK_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#prefix'] = '<div class="custom-wrapper">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I didn't try yet your 2nd solution but I want to discuss more the 1st.
It looks like `search-block-form.tpl.php` only uses a variable `$search_form` which according to the doc, is the complete form ready to output. So I suppose it is just a string and I can't change much in there (unless using regex). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You asked about adding a custom wrapper. So it's enough for this. Otherwise use 2nd solution. It's much more powerful.